# The template is not rendering inside the element app in remote server but works in local env

Tags: laravel, vue.js

UPDATE:: I believe that it has to do with Vue Router, when I use that, it will not work in the remote env. I made sure that I installed vue-router package. The question is why it would show empty.

---

In my local environment, the Vue JS setup works fine but when I deploy it in the remote server, it shows blank. There is no console error or anything to even debug.

here is my app.js file where I know i set it up corrctly

```
import './bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
//import Routes from './routes';
import App from './views/App';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Login from "./components/Login";
import Dashboard from "../js/components/user/Dashboard";

    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    window.Axios = require('axios');

    const router = new VueRouter({
       mode: 'history',
       routes:[
          {
             path: '/',
             name: 'login',
             component: Login
          },{
             path: '/dashboard',
             name: 'dashboard',
             component: Dashboard
          }
       ]
    });

    const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       template: '<div>hello</div>',
       //router: router,
       //render: h => h(App),
    });

    export default app;
```

As you can see i'm only trying to spit out "hello" in the view but it's not even showing anything.
How do i debug?

The server is in linux env and using apache web server. My local is in php artisan server. Vue Js is a part of laravel 6.* and shown inside the blade template.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>----</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://159.203.117.201/stockman/css/styles.css">
    <script>window.laravelToken = 'fzBmxRrJJALZ2CoUVQXbII9LxXbC7YuCbnmLwji0';</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="----/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How are you deploying? Make sure you compile your assets.

Comment: compiled with webpack. if that is what you were asking about

Comment: Did you include the full Vue build with the template compiler?